# Symfony - How to regenerate crud for Entity from a controller

Tags: command-line, controller, crud, symfony

I would like to regenerate crud for all my Entities from my controller once I enter specific url. The example below runs a command for only one Entity for demonstration purpose. When I navigate to the path '/reCrud', my browser will spin forever but the command never executes. What is quite interesting is that the same code, when I run 'cache:clear' instead, will run just fine.

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class CrudController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/reCrud")
     */
    public function reCrudAction()
    {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new StringInput('doctrine:generate:crud AdminBundle:Klient --overwrite --no-debug');
        // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

Perhaps this is only an environment configuration issue. Feel free to chunk that code and test it on your machine. Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It spins because underneath it is waiting for you to enter stuff:

```
Welcome to the Doctrine2 CRUD generator  



This command helps you generate CRUD controllers and templates.

First, give the name of the existing entity for which you want to generate a CRUD
(use the shortcut notation like AcmeBlogBundle:Post)

The Entity shortcut name [AdminBundle:Klient]:
```

**Solution:**

Try adding `-n` option which is:

```
-n, --no-interaction             Do not ask any interactive question
```

So in the end your command would be something like this:

```
doctrine:generate:crud --entity=AdminBundle:Klient --overwrite --no-debug --no-interaction
```

Comment: Great ! Thank You. I also had to add "--entity=" before it worked, but you solved it. Thanks. You can edit your anser as below:

doctrine:generate:crud --entity=AdminBundle:Klient --overwrite --no-debug --no-interaction